# Display error dialog from batch file

Tags: java, windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have this windows batch file which starts Java application

```
java -jar bin/felix.jar 
msg "%username%" JVM version 1.8.0_20 is not installed
```

Is there a way to display message when Java is not found on the computer?

Answer (score 2):

This could help. Maybe

```
@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -version:1.7 -version > nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto found
SET msg=Not found
goto end

:found
SET msg=Found
:end


echo msgbox"%msg%">a.vbs &;a.vbs
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without vbs script?

Comment: Not that I know of...however, I found this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/usermessages.php